# Stop a dynamically loaded script when switching to a new page via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, execution

I am relatively new to web dev. I have an HTML5 application with multiple pages, where each has animation (driven by a ticker). I managed to implement dynamic page loading via Ajax and php for the pages but there is a big problem. The scripts don't terminate when I dynamically load a different page (clicking on link to different page). Is there a way to completely wipe out everything that was loaded/initiated when dynamically switching pages? As if I simply switched to a new page altogether? 
Right now the php just loads the page and then I replace the existing HTML in the target div with the freshly loaded page. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help with the specific issue.

Comment: When you load a new "page", you should have a cleanup routine that stops any ongoing scripts, removes handlers. If that is too hard, you are probably working with a lot of global functions instead of testable, reusable JavaScript objects. It's kind of a really big architecture question, not a good fit for SO since one could write a book about it.

Comment: you can try aborting the ajax requests under progress, but the server might be in middle of processing. Data might be sent back, but the browser simply wont care.